# Jmeter If condition to check JSR223 variable value not working

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am kind of stuck here, so I am new to Jmeter and trying to perform performance testing on bunch of APIs.

So below is the flow with relevant codes.

```
> HTTP Authorization Manager 
> HTTP Sampler (Base API) 
    > JSON Extractor
> ForEach Controller
    > JSR223 Postprocessor (change API Path with if condition)
    > If Controller (Check if value is not "true")
  > HTTP Sampler
```

Below is code for JSR223 (So I am checking if the variable from for loop is equal a regex then append additional parameters) and if the a variable path is null or empty then set a variable as "true"

```
def currentURL = vars.get("currentURL")
def modifiedURL = ""
    
log.info("currentURL: " + currentURL)
log.info("modifiedURL1: " + modifiedURL)

if (currentURL.equals("example")){
   modifiedURL = 'example?parameter1&parameter2'
   log.info("modifiedURL2: " + modifiedURL)
} else if (currentURL.equals("example2")){
   modifiedURL = 'example2?parameter3&parameter4'
   log.info("modifiedURL3: " + modifiedURL)
}

log.info("modifiedURL4: " + modifiedURL)

vars.put("modifiedURL", modifiedURL)

def ifvar = ${__groovy(vars.get("modifiedURL") != "",)}

def condition = ${__groovy(vars.get("modifiedURL") != null && !vars.get("modifiedURL").isEmpty(),)}

log.info("ifvar: " + ifvar)

log.info("condition: " + condition)
```

Now the if loop is as below

```
${__groovy(vars.get("modifiedURL") != "",)}
```

Now last HTTP Sampler is same as base with added paths as endpoint. e.g for 1st HTTP Sampler path is "https://API.com/path1/" and last one is "https://API.com/path1/${modifiedURL}"

But for some reason last one is running with same path as 1st HTTP sampler "https://API.com/path1/", ideally i would expect it to only run twice https://API.com/path1/example?paramete1&paramter2 and https://API.com/path1/example2?paramete3&paramter4

```
NOTE: I edited the JSR223 to debug further, for some reason in the logs ifvar and condition shows false, even though modifiedURL is not empty or null
```

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see where do write the value of `modifiedURL` into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) so my expectation is that the last line of your "code" should look like:

```
vars.put('modifiedURL', modifiedURL)
```

You might also want to check this `modifiedURL` variable value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter), it might be the case your "condition" doesn't work as you expect

Comment: That's the thing, when if condition of JSR223 satisfies it should put a value to modifiedURL otherwise it will remain empty, I have tried vars.put('modifiedURL', modifiedURL) as well, still the if controller never works and HTTP sampler runs with empty modifiedURL